# Why doesn't gphoto2 trigger in time

Tags: usb, canon

I want to remote-controle my DSLR with an Ubuntu-PC and make a timelapse-video. I found out, that i should use gphoto2 for that. But i've got a problem with it.I type into the terminal:

```
gphoto2 --capture-image -F 10 -I 5
```

Thereby gphoto2 should take 10 Pictures with a interval of 5 seconds. But now gphoto2 sometimes needs more time than 5 seconds for one picture and it sometimes doesn't trigger before 6 to 8 seconds. For a timelapse-video thats very bad of course.

But that's not a problem of the shutter speed. The shutter speed is only a split second. When i trigger by myself on the camera the picture is saved in approx. half a second and the camera is ready to take the next picture. But gphoto2 calculates up and down and saves something and needs much more time for one photo.

Is it possible to turns this fuss?

I'd be very thankful if you could help me.

btw: I'm using 13.10, the cmera is a Canon EOS 700d (Canon EOS Rebel T5i) and it's attached to my pc via the included USB-cble.